# how to replace a string with a dynamic string

Tags: regex, perl

#### Case 1.

I have a string of **alphabets** like `fthhdtrhththjgyhjdtygbh`.  Using regex I want to change it to `ftxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`, i.e, keep the first two letters and replace the rest by x.

After a lot of googling, I achieved this:

```perl
s/^(\w\w)(\w+)/$1 . "x" x length($2)/e;
```

#### Case 2.

I have a string of **alphabets** like `sdsABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEsdf`. Using regex I want to change it to `sdsABCDExyxyxyABCDEsdf`, i.e, keep the first and last `ABCDE` and replace the ABCDE in the middle with `xy`.
I achieved this:

```perl
s/ABCDE((ABCDE)+)ABCDE/$len = length($1)\/5; ABCDE."xy"x $len . ABCDE/e;
```

**Problem** : I am not happy with my solution to the mentioned problem. Is there any better or neat solution to the mentioned problem.

**Contraint** : Only one regex have to be used.

Sorry for the poor English in the title and the body of the problem, english isn't my first language. Please ask in comments if anything is not clear.

Comment: What's the problem you have with your existing solution?

Comment: It's not, um, neat in my opinion. very complex regexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Task 1: Simplify the password hider regex

Use a [Positive Lookbehind Assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) to replace all word characters preceded by two other word characters.  This removes the need for the [`/e` Modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers):

```
my $str = 'fthhdtrhththjgyhjdtygbh';

$str =~ s/(?<=\w{2})\w/x/g;

print $str;
```

Outputs:

```
ftxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

#### Task 2: Translate inner repeated pattern regex

Use both a Positive Lookbehind and Lookahead Assertion to replace all `ABCDE` that are bookended by the same string:

```
my $str = 'sdsABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEsdf';

$str =~ s/(?<=(ABCDE))\1(?=\1)/xy/g;

print $str, "\n";
```

Output:

```
sdsABCDExyxyxyABCDEsdf
```

Answer (score 1):

One regex, less redundancy using `\1` to refer to first captured group,

```
s|(ABCDE)\K (\1+) (?=\1)| "xy" x (length($2)/length($1)) |xe;
```